# Prove that for any set $A$ there is some $x \notin A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am working through Hrbacek and Jech's *Introduction to Set Theory* and am not yet feeling totally confident in my proof writing, so I figured I would post solutions on here to get feedback. Is this a valid proof in ZF?

***Claim***

For any set $A$ there is some $x \notin A$.

***Proof***

Suppose (toward contradiction) there is a set $A$ such that for all sets $x, x \in A$. Consider the property $P(x):x\notin x$. By the axiom of separation, there exists a set $B$ such that $x\in B$ iff $x \in A$ and $x \notin x$.

Now, either $B \in B$ or $B \notin B$.

Suppose $B \in B.$ Then $B\notin B.$

On the other hand, suppose $B \notin B$. But $B \in A$ also (since for all sets $x, x\in A$). It follows that $B \in B$.

What did we show? We showed that $B \in B$ iff $B \notin B$, a contradiction. So our hypothesis was false, and for all sets $A$ there exists a set $x:x\notin A$.

***Questions***

Is there a direct proof of this statement? Here are the axioms the book has introduced so far:

- *Existence*
- *Extension*
- *Separation*
- *Pairing*
- *Union*
- *Powerset*

Doing a bit of research, I noticed that there are arguments that use other theorems. For example, we know that for all sets $A,|P(A)|$ is strictly larger than $|A|$. So there must be some $x\in P(A): x \notin A$. But I have not proved this theorem so did not want to use it. I also noticed there are some who claim one can invoke the foundation axiom and make an argument using that. That path seems less clear then me - in any case; I am interested in other proofs of the statement.

Plus, the argument is essentially the same as the [argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4676799/the-set-of-all-sets-does-not-exist) I made to prove the claim that the set of all sets does not exist; the original statement is just worded slightly differently. So I'm thinking I might be on the right track and am noticing what the authors intended for me to notice    ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There is no (logical) difference between your claim here and “the set of all sets does not exist”

Comment: $A \notin A$ by the axiom of regularity.

Comment: @DavidLui You're correct, but as this proof demonstrates, you don't need regularity to show that there can't be a set of all sets.

Comment: @EdwardH I think the proof I gave is proof by contradiction (I assumed ~P and derived a contradiction)

Comment: A more straightforward way of presenting that argument: Given a set $A$, you define the set $B=\{x\in A:x\notin x\}$ and then you prove that $B\notin A$. Of course the proof that $B\notin A$ is a proof by contradiction. The only axiom used is Separation.

Comment: Is this the argument?

Let $B \in A$ and note that either $B \in B$ or $B \notin B$. If $B \in B$, then $B \notin B$ by definition of $B$. But if $B\notin B$ then $B \notin A$ or $B \in B$. Since $B \in A$ by hypothesis, we conclude $B \in B$. So $B \in B$ iff $B \notin B$, a contradiction. So $B \notin A$ after all.